# Select SQl where many things can be equal except one colmn

Tags: sql, count, firebird, difference

```
select * from cards 
where name=name and streetname=streetname and streetnumber<>streetnumber
```

this is what I tried and had in my mind but to no avail

What I am trying is that I want only be shown

when the streetnumber is different.

so for example

```
    Rene ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 11
    Rene ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 23
    Rene ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 11
    Rene ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 17
    Rene ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 11
    Rene ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 11

    Anna ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 11
    Anna ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 11
    Anna ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 11
    Anna ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 11

    John ter Horst : AvanueRoad : 11
```

But i have over 40.000 things to check so i cannot look manual for

So i guess i need to implement some counting into it

I would Only like to have Rene ter Horst to be returned because it has differences

but I do not want to have Anna or John Returned and all the others who have same name and addresses and house numbers

any help and terminology is appreciated*

I want to stress out if i was not clear, I cannot search for anything specific the database has to figure out itself that it counts 6 times the name Rene and 6 times AvanueRoad and it has not 6 times the same house number. Sorry if my question sounds vague

Comment: Have you thought of using SELECT DISTINCT?

Answer (score 3):

Think about this using aggregation rather than just selection.  A `having` clause should do the filtering you want:

```
select name
from cards
group by name
having min(streetname) <> max(streetname) or
       min(streetnumber) <> max(streetnumber);
```

Your data does not have any `NULL` values.  If it does and you want to treat them as distinct values, then the logic needs to be a bit more complex:

```
select name
from cards
group by name
having min(streetname) <> max(streetname) or count(*) <> count(streetname) or
       min(streetnumber) <> max(streetnumber) or count(*) <> count(streetnumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way is probably the GROUP BY that Gordon suggested, but this is another way to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM cards c
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM cards
     WHERE c.Name = Name
     AND c.HouseNumber != HouseNumber);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the SQL Unique modifier:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `streetnumber` FROM `cards`
```

Comment: The word is `DISTINCT`, not `UNIQUE`.

Comment: What's the point of `WHERE name=name AND streetname=streetname`? Those will always be true (unless one of the columns is `NULL`).

Comment: Okay guys, I really messed up. This was a TERRIBLE answer.